# Live displaying PHP output on a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, live, display

I would like to display the output of my PHP script in a div in live. I'm using Laravel 5.4
My PHP code :

```
$cmd = 'ping -c 10 127.0.0.1';

while (@ ob_end_flush());
$proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
echo '<pre>';
while (!feof($proc))
{
    echo fread($proc, 4096);
    @ flush();
}
echo '</pre>';

return view('layouts/test');
```

When I load the page, my function work and it's live displaying but it's take up the whole page.
I tried to use Ajax, I was able to retrieve the output but it's not live displaying.
Someone have an idea ?

Comment: if it works, what is the problem? taking the whole page? did you try to apply some style to the div (assuming the content is nested) like Width, overflow, etc.. to style how the displayed result is shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the script in an iframe should work.

```
<iframe src="/script.php"></iframe>
```

Or alternatively if you need it to load after a specific action

```
<iframe id='myIframe'></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('myIframe').src = '/script.php';
<script>
```

Comment: The problem he's likely having with the Ajax is that it's waiting for the script to finish before it displays the output, so flushing the output buffer won't have an effect. 


Using an iframe should make it treat it like loading a page normally so the flushed output should display as the script runs. Being in an iframe will keep the content within the iframe and won't affect the surrounding page so it'll fix the 'whole page' issue.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Hall. It's what I looked for. It's working with a simple index.php page. I will try now to include that in my Laravel project.

Comment: @edward if this answer works for you please rate and accept it